# View Controller must refresh itself when coming to front

Tags: ios, swift

I have an app that I am developing using Swift 4.0. I have a View Controller on which I am showing some useful information and user can interact with them. Lets call this as BaseViewController.

**What I am doing:**
The BaseViewController is starting different other ViewControllers, and than user can dismiss those viewControllers and come back to BaseViewController.

**What I want:**
Now I want that whenever user comes back to BaseViewController it gets itself updated. I know it can be done using Protocols, but I just want a simple way. Like in Android there is onResume method to perform updates whenever Activity comes into active state.

I think there is no need to share code as starting other viewController from one viewcontroller is pretty simple. I just wanted to know the better approach. Thanks in advance

**UPDATE: THIS IS HOW I AM CALLING NEXT CONTROLLER OVER BASE CONTROLLER**

```
let dialogRegisterForEventVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main",bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "idDialogRegisterForEventVC") as! DialogRegisterForEventVC
    dialogRegisterForEventVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    dialogRegisterForEventVC.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
    dialogRegisterForEventVC.isUserLogin = isLogin

    self.present(dialogRegisterForEventVC, animated: true) {

    }
```

Comment: What ever u need to refresh, put all things in ViewWillAppear or ViewDidAppear

Comment: check updated question

Answer (score 0):

You can always go with [viewWillAppear](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621510-viewwillappear) Method

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
  print("This is called when coming back to Base View Controller")
}
```

Use your refresh code here. This is called when you pop your `viewController`

Comment: Can you let me know in which case it is not working.? Share some piece of code what are you doing to refresh.?

Comment: I want to run the service that fetches the fresh content from server, but the problem is that the viewWillAppear is only gets called on first time when BaseViewController starts

Answer (score 0):

There different cases and you need to handle them for example
If you presenting another viewController on top of this you should use

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)
```

If you need to refresh the view if the app comes in foreground state you need such code :

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(willResignActive), name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
    }

  @objc func willResignActive(_ notification: Notification) {
       refreshMyView()
    }
```

Also, you can create delegate that your viewController can call to update this view controller. And one more option is to make your view controller observer of custom notification in Notification center and to push this notification once when you need to refresh the view controller.

If you using the notification center just be sure that your UI changes are on the main thread.

Comment: I am presenting the other view over it, but viewWillApear did not call again

Comment: Than you have problem in your hierarchy, of view controllers and presenters. You can test with the custom notification observer, I think it will be fine. But for sure you should double-check why viewWillAppear is not called.